# How to bind JSON data to JQUERY Datatable and refresh it using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vb.net, datatable

I am trying to connect SQL server data with Jquery datable using JSON and Ajax. But it is not working.

I have generated JSON data using the web method
as below

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetQueryInfo() As String
    Dim Jsonresult As String = Nothing     
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim constr As String = Constr
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from COMPLAINTTYPE", con)
            con.Open()
            Dim MyDataReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(MyDataReader)
            Jsonresult = GetJson(dt)
            Return Jsonresult
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Function
 Public Function GetJson(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String
    Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
        Next
        rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
End Function
```

I am getting JSON while invoking the web method as below

```
[{"ID":89,"COMPLAINTTYPE":"Motherboard complaint","CTYPE_ABS":"Motherboardcomplaint"},
{"ID":90,"COMPLAINTTYPE":"CMOS batter not working","CTYPE_ABS":"CMOSbatternotworking"},
{"ID":91,"COMPLAINTTYPE":"Memory damaged","CTYPE_ABS":"Memorydamaged"},
{"ID":92,"COMPLAINTTYPE":"SMPS damaged","CTYPE_ABS":"SMPSdamaged"},
{"ID":93,"COMPLAINTTYPE":"97472","CTYPE_ABS":"97472"},
{"ID":94,"COMPLAINTTYPE":"6635","CTYPE_ABS":"6635"},{"ID":95,"COMPLAINTTYPE":"new
omplaintfjjf","CTYPE_ABS":"newomplaintfjjf"}]
```

Here is my HTML markup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#eg1').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "DataJason.asmx/GetQueryInfo",
                    "type": "Get",
                    "datatype": "Json",
                },
                "Columns": [
                   { title: "ID" },
                   { title: "CTYPE" },
                   { title: "CTYPE_ABS" }
                ]

            });
        });
    </script>
 <table id="eg1"   class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none">
        <thead> <asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" Text="Add new Complaints"  CssClass="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-xs btn-primary"/>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Complaint</th>
            <th>Ctype</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

I am getting this error alert " DataTables warning: table id=eg1 - Requested unknown parameter 'ID' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/4" so I checked with this link datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4 it says the field ID is missing,but the JSON is returning the ID
Can you please explain why this is not working?

Comment: *"is not working"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement with no debugging or error details provided

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, I am getting this error alert " DataTables warning: table id=eg1 - Requested unknown parameter 'ID' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4" so I checked with this link https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4 it says the field ID is missing,but the JSON is returning the ID